# Error in Xilinx ISE Design Suite 12.3 (EDK)

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I have installed Xilinx ISE Design Suite 12.3 in my laptop.

Now, i want to open my EDK (Xilinx Platform Studio).

But i got this error...

```
    setting XILINX_EDK=C:\Xlinx\12.3\ISE_DS\EDK
    Environment variable XILINX is not set -A compitable version of ISE tools must be
    installed and setup for EDK to run.

     Press enter to close
```

Can anyone help me solve this  problem??

Comment: What is you OS? Is in windows 7 or 8?

Comment: Have you considered updating to the newest ISE, "Xilinx ISE Design Suite 14.7"; maybe that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't installed ISE -  only the EDK - so when the EDK looks for ISE it doesn't find it.
Solution - go to the Xilinx download site an download ISE. Do yourself a favour and get 14.7 - it's still buggy, but has fewer bugs. Note that if you are on windows 10, ISE won't run at all, and you need to use the Virtualbox image (it's free, if slow) that installs an ubuntu VM with everything you need. This is also on the Xilinx download page.
It's important to make sure versions line up - if you have an older EDK, it won't play nicely with newer ISE, which is one of the useful bits of loading the entire thing as a VM - everything matches. Be aware too  that you need 14.7 for spartan 6 and earlier, but after that (7 series and up), you need Vivado (ISE equivalent) and Vitis (EDK), and that to install those, the complete installer is found by installing VITIS with the 'install Vivado' option.